# how to add extra fields in skadate

Tags: php, oxwall

I am new with `Skadate`, which is a dating software build in PHP 5 and template engine `Smarty`. I need to add an extra field for user edit section.

Currently there is default user fields in the admin section. I need to add an extra field. e.g. Country : Country list

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: which version are you using of Skadate?

Comment: have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To add new profile question you have to utilize admin panel. Just go to URL **www.yoursitename.com/admin/users/profile-questions**

On this page you will get options for add **Sections** and **Profile questions**. 
Fill up the form and save using submit button.

Regarding your query, To add a question with answer as drop down or list, you need to add them with **Answer type field as drop down**.

Once you create new question if your site supports multiple language then you have to put corresponding value in **yoursite.com/admin/settings/languages**

FYI: new questions are stored under base section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using idatemedia's [dating software](https://www.idatemedia.com) so there is no smarty templates. It's pretty much all straight PHP and version 7.2. I'm able to add a custom field but since I know mysql I prefer to add it via php and insert the field into the table structure. Most new fields I add are not blob text fields. They are characters of around 1000.